# Railway - configuring repo access

Tags: github

When I am trying to configure github app on my Railway account, I keep getting error message, so unable to connect. Not sure what is wrong, but keep getting this:

[image: A screenshot of Mozilla Firefox navigated to https://github.com/apps/railway-app/installations/new displaying an illustration of a unicorn and the message: "This page is taking too long to load. Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists."]

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GitHub internal error ([500 Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)) and is not fixable by any action of your own. Either wait and try again later, or reach out to GitHub Support as the error says.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused by the course CS50x, as I have found on GitHub discussion, due to (I think I will not use right terminology here but will appreciate correction) too many people involved in solving same problem sets. Once I have opened new GitHub account and split my CSx courses series from other project, the problem has gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).